# converting g changes to angular velocity

Tags: accelerometer

I am trying to get angular velocity from accelerometer. I can get G values and degrees of object on 3d space.

Can I convert g values somehow to angular velocity?

I was thinking taking differentiation of angular displacement but I dont know whether it will be accurate or not.

Answer (score 2):

Using RCF = 1.118 x Radius x (rpm/1000)\$^2\$ you can convert between g force (relative centrifugal force) and RPM for a certain "off-centre" distance (in millimetres): -

[image]

Or use [this](http://insilico.ehu.es/mini_tools/rcf_rpm.php) calculator or the following table: -

[image]

Once you have obtained RPM you can calculate the speed of rotation at that radius (angular velocity).

It's not a very electronicky subject on the face of it but I've used it for determining if some crystals can be used when rotated.

Comment: I think you meant centripetal force. Centrifugal is a fictional force like ether :)

Comment: @efox29 No, I believe I do mean centrifugal force: http://www.sorbio.com/index.php/rpm-vs-rcf

Comment: Centripetal force is that force that tethers an object at a certain radius when spun thus counteracting the outwards throwing centrifugal force. I guess it's roundabout the same thing!